# How to Lazy load images in JavaFx?

Tags: java, javafx

Is it possible to do a lazy loading for images in JavaFx?
It has a hundreds of picture and it took time to load the images.
I would like to implement lazy loading so when I am scrolling on the stackpane, the images will also load.

```
            File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

            for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
                Image img = new Image(listOfFiles[i].toURI().toString());
            }
```

Comment: You would benefit from a "virtual" control such as `ListView` or `GridView` (the latter is from _ControlsFX_). The idea is you'd only load the image when the cell is meant to display the image. You could implement some sort of caching to stop reloading images over and over.

Comment: The last time I used `GridView` for something like this, caching was absolutely necessary: The cells were updated multiple times when scrolling by a small amount, even when they remained in the viewport...

Answer (score 1):

You can use background loading see in the documentation.
With the flag **true**

```
Image myImage= new Image("/icons/test.png",true);
```

Comment: I've already tried that but I have the same issue which is the images took time to load.